# postgresql concurrent queries debug

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, locking, plpgsql

There is a multithreaded application executing some PL/pgsql function. That function produces record inserts to a critically important resource( table ). Also it executes some select/update/etc operations while executing.

The issue is, sometimes we face duplicate( 2-3 ) records each one passed to the function in a parallel thread. And they all are inserted into table as a function execution result, while they should not.

It happens, because both transactions are executed in parallel, and have no idea that the same record is being prepared to insert in a parallel transaction.

The table is critically important and all kinds of `LOCK TABLE` are extremely not welcomed (`LOCK FOR SHARE MODE` meanwhile gave as some useful experience).

So, the question is, is there any best practice how to organize PL/pgsql function working with a critical resource (table) to be executed by multithreaded app and producing no harmful locks on this resource?

PS. I know, that some thread partinioning by record.ID in the app is a possible solution. But I.m interested in a PL/pgsql solution first of all.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you either do not have a Primary/Unique key, or that by "duplicates", you mean attributes other than the Primary/Unique key? Locking or serialized access are the only ways to ensure the uniqueness of your entries, or at least that I can think of. A resource available in Postgresql 9.2+ is Serializable Snapshot isolation (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI) but that might be a bit heavyweight for your needs.

Comment: We have a PK constraint, but it is a logical duplicateness, not a straightforward field-by-field matching. And Serializable Isolation level is not a acceptable solution for us: it produces serialization access denies for parallel transaction that can unpredictably affect application behavior. Thanks for advice anyway!

Comment: If your primary key allows duplicates, it's not a primary key is it? What *precisely* do you mean by duplicateness.

Comment: Well @Richard Huxton you are right about that. Building the Unique index is a possible solution no doubt. But im looking for more flexible solution (pg_advisory_lock seems to be the best candidate at the moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you can use a advisory locks - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html .With these locks some subset of numbers. I used it for synchronization of parallel inserts with success.

Comment: Unfortunately advisory_lock cant do what I would like him to do. Actually, expected to find a database engine module, that would allow me to declare some lock rule like 'select do_lock(*) from resource_tbl where id between 1 and 100' that would mean database will not allow to insert new records with id from interval from 1 to 100. All existing techniques, as far as I realised, allow me to lock some already existing records only. Anyway, I came to the conclusions I needed, thanks for paying attention to the question!